# Isomorphism of factor groups

Tags: group-theory

I came across an intuitive statement on factor groups that I realized I did not know how to prove.

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H \unlhd G, K \unlhd G$ such that $H \cong K$. I want to show that $G/H \cong G/K$.

I'm not sure how exactly to construct such an isomorphism from an isomorphism $\varphi: H \to K$. Is that the correct approach? By extending such an isomorphism to an automorphism on $\varphi^{\uparrow}:G \to G$, then we could apply the First Isomorphism Theorem to the composition of the natural homomorphism $\mu: G \to G/K$ and that automorphism (for $\ker \mu\varphi^{\uparrow} = H$, if such a $\varphi^\uparrow$ exists).

**Edit:** Hamou points out this is false in the infinite case: can it still be salvaged in the finite case? Are there restrictions we can put on $G, H,$ and $K$ such that this is true?

Comment: If H is isomorphic to K, maybe define the isomorphism by mapping H's generators to K's generators? Then by the definition of the quotient group, the fibers of $G/H$ and $G/K$ will be isomorphic, which should be enough.

Comment: The reason that you cannot prove it is that it is not true, even for finite groups. There is a counterexample of order $8$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Just out of curiosity, would you mind providing this counterexample?

Comment: $G$ abelian of order $8$, $H$ and $K$ of order $2$ - try and find it yourself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2\Bbb Z\cong 3\Bbb Z$, but $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

A finite counterexample: take $G=C_4 \times V_4$, say $C_4=\langle a: a^4=1\rangle$ and $V_4=\langle x,y: x^2=1=y^2, xy=yx\rangle$. Now take $H=\langle a^2\rangle \times \langle x \rangle$, and $K=\{1\} \times V_4$. Then $H \cong K \cong V_4$. But $G/H \cong V_4$, and $G/K \cong C_4.$